# Sharing Xcode Project Manually and Data Security

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode13.3.1

I need to share my Xcode project manually with a customer support representative through email. My concern is that I do not know if my project contains any sensitive information that no third party should see.

My credentials and provisioning profile are all set in the project so I can deploy on physical devices. Can people use this information (or anything else) or am I worrying about nothing? If it is a better practice to remove personal info in these situations, what exactly and how should I remove them?

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your certificate and provisioning profiles are not stored in the directory of the project, they are stored on the keychain and in a separate folder, respectively. All that is stored in the project are the identifiers.

Unless you have sensitive information in the source code, it is generally safe to share the directory where your project is.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I wait for a few more hours for others to chime in, and then I will accept your answer.